# All subsets of a list without comma at the end of one-element subsets

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find all subsets of list [1,2,3]. I use the following code:

```
import itertools


def powerset(iterable):
  xs = list(iterable)
  # note we return an iterator rather than a list
  return itertools.chain.from_iterable( itertools.combinations(xs,n) for n in range(len(xs)+1) )



N_set = [1,2,3]
my_subset = list(powerset(N_set))
print(my_subset)
```

and the output is:

[(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]

But, I don't want to have a comma after one-element subsets. I want the output to be:

[(), (1), (2), (3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]

Is there any simple way we can get that?

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand what you're asking for ... `(1,)` is the way python prints a tuple that has only a single element.  Are you just concerned with the way it is being printed?  Or do you want to change the output data-structure?  If the latter, what differences do you want exactly?

Comment: Why don't you want a comma? That is the syntax for python tuples.

Comment: @mgilson I know about tuple. I just want to change the way it is printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(1,)` is the syntax for a 1-element Python tuple whose only element is `1`. `(1)` is just `1` in grouping parentheses. If you want your output to look like a valid Python data structure, your output is already correct.

If you don't want your output to look like a valid data structure, you need to customize the way you're printing it. For example,

```
for subset in powerset(N_set):
    if not subset:
        print('<empty>')
    else:
        print(', '.join(map(str, subset)))
```